# How to type Org Mode's `M-` bindings in Emacs for Mac?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, osx

I'm having a hell of a time with getting Org Mode's key bindings to work.

I thought that maybe the difficulties I was having had to do with what [this page](http://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-keys.html) describes, since I was using Emacs text-mode via `Terminal.app` (on a Mac).

So I decided to try [Emacs for Mac](http://emacsformacosx.com/), which (presumably) I could use as a free-standing application, thereby circumventing whatever problems `Terminal.app` may be causing.

But it turns out that, *with Emacs for Mac I can type even fewer Org Mode key-bound commands!*

(In this post, I will abbreviate Emacs for Mac as McE, and Emacs via `Terminal.app` as TME, short for "text-mode Emacs".)

Let me start with the case of `<M-right>`, by way of example.

According to `describe-bindings` (`C-h b`) for Org Mode, `<M-right>` should be bound to `org-metaright`.  This is not terribly informative, but the documentation for `org-metaright` says:

> org-metaright is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `org.el'.
>
> (org-metaright &optional ARG)
>
> Demote a subtree, a list item or move table column to right.
>   In front of a drawer or a block keyword, indent it correctly.
>   With no specific context, calls the Emacs default `forward-word'.
>   See the individual commands for more information.

Now, suppose that `org-mode` is the buffer's major mode, point is at a subtree's heading, and I type the key sequence I'd use for `<M-right>`, namely, <kbd>esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>→</kbd>.

If I do this in TME, the subtree is demoted, exactly as the documentation says, but if I do it in McE, all I get is that point advances forward by one word.

Indeed, in McE, if I type the same sequence (<kbd>esc</kbd> , <kbd>→</kbd>) into `describe-key` (`C-h k`), I don't get the documentation for `org-metaright`, but rather the one for `forward-word`:

> ESC <right> (translated from <escape> <right>) runs the command
>   forward-word, which is an interactive built-in function in `C source
>   code'.
>
> It is bound to M-f, ESC <right>.
>
> (forward-word &optional ARG)
>
> Move point forward ARG words (backward if ARG is negative).
>   If ARG is omitted or nil, move point forward one word.
>   Normally returns t.
>   If an edge of the buffer or a field boundary is reached, point is left there
>   and the function returns nil.  Field boundaries are not noticed if
>   `inhibit-field-text-motion' is non-nil.

---

It gets worse.

`<M-right>` at least works correctly in TME, but `<M-S-right>` I can't get to work anywhere.

According to `describe-bindings`, `<M-S-right>` is supposed to be bound to (you guessed it) `org-shiftmetaright`.  In McE, however, if I type into `describe-key` the sequence for `<M-S-right>` (namely, <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>, where I'm pressing the last two keys simultaneously), I again get the docs for `forward-word` pretty much as shown earlier, except for a small change in the first line:

> ESC <right> (translated from <escape> <S-right>) runs the command
>   forward-word, which is an interactive built-in function in `C source
>   code'.
>   ...

The silver lining is the mention of <escape> <S-right> in this first line, because it shows that McE is at least detecting the <kbd>shift</kbd> press (which is the reason I bothered to install McE in the first place).  Unfortunately, it is discarding that piece information, and mistranslating what's left (after all ESC <right> should be bound to `org-metaright`, not to `forward-word`).

Doing the same thing in TME produces:

> ESC <right> (translated from ESC M-O C) runs the command
>   org-metaright, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `org.el'.
>
> It is bound to <M-right>, ESC <right>, C-c C-x r, <menu-bar> <Org>
>   <Edit Structure> <Demote Heading>, <menu-bar> <Tbl> <Column> <Move
>   Column Right>.
>
> (org-metaright &optional ARG)
>
> Demote a subtree, a list item or move table column to right.
>   In front of a drawer or a block keyword, indent it correctly.
>   With no specific context, calls the Emacs default `forward-word'.
>   See the individual commands for more information.

...which sounds a bit better (it's the documentation for *some* Org Mode command at least!), but it seems that the shift is not getting through at all.  I can't figure out what the `M-O C` in the first line is referring to.

---

What can I do to get these key bindings to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always access the meta prefix via

```
C-x @ m
```

which is bound to `event-apply-meta-modifier`.
Thus `C-x @ m <right>` in `org-mode` is bound to `org-metaright` and `C-x @ m S-<right>` is bound to `org-shiftmetaright`.

In general the `ESC` key is only related to the meta prefix in front of ordinary characters, not in front of special keys such as `<f11>` or `<right>`. The following two paragraphs of the Elisp manual explain this:

> Keymaps do not directly record bindings for the meta characters.
>   Instead, meta characters are regarded for purposes of key lookup as
>   sequences of two characters, the first of which is <ESC> (or whatever
>   is currently the value of ‘meta-prefix-char’).  Thus, the key ‘M-a’ is
>   internally represented as ‘<ESC> a’, and its global binding is found
>   at the slot for ‘a’ in ‘esc-map’ (*note Prefix Keys::).
>
> This conversion applies only to characters, not to function keys or
>   other input events; thus, ‘M-<end>’ has nothing to do with ‘<ESC>
>   <end>’.

from section 21.3 "Format of Keymaps"

Another approach is to use the option `org-use-extra-keys`.  This is turned on automatically for emacs in a terminal and provides a number of alternative bindings.  In particular `M-<right>` may be invoked by either `C-c C-x r` or `<ESC> <right>`.  Also it defines a speed key `r` for use when at the beginning of a headline.  See "Using Org on a tty" under the "Miscellaneous" section of the org manual.

Answer (score 3):

Use [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/features.html) instead of the built-in Terminal. iTerm2 lets you swap all the modifier keys on the keyboard however you like, right in the Preferences pane. iTerm is a work of art and it's open source.

When you make the switch to Linux try the technique I describe in the link below. My answer was not selected as Best Answer, but I think it is.
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60235/mapping-super-keys-to-control-without-xmodmap/156645#156645

Answer (score 0):

- if you need <kbd>⎋ ESC</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>, just type <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>.
- If you need <kbd>⎋ ESC</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>, just type <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>.
- If you need <kbd>⎋ ESC</kbd> all the time in MacBook Pro Touch Bar model, just type <kbd>⌃ control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. As miss Touch Bar is so cute, <kbd>⎋ ESC</kbd> sometimes disappears.
- I removed all buttons from unintentional miss-Touch Bar, such as <kbd>Siri</kbd>, <kbd>Volume Control</kbd>, <kbd>Brightness Control</kbd>, etc. **Only My <kbd>⎋ ESC</kbd>.** Nothing except one <kbd>⎋ ESC</kbd> is in my miss-Touch Bar. No more miss-Touch. I finally got the best Emacs machine ever.