# How to extend the <ESC> => M- translation to non-character keys?

Tags: key-bindings

This question is a follow-up to [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3991/882) (q.v.).

I understand that Emacs interprets <kbd>esc</kbd> as `M-` only when the keystroke that follows it corresponds to a "character" (e.g. <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>;</kbd>, etc.), as opposed to, e.g., <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>home</kbd>, etc.

What can I add to my `.emacs` file to extend the <kbd>esc</kbd> ⇒ `M-` interpretation to the case where the following key is a "non-character" key?

---

OK, the following snippet takes care of my immediate problem, **but it's not an answer to my question** (see below):

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 S-down] 'org-shiftmetadown)
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 S-up] 'org-shiftmetaup)
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 S-right] 'org-shiftmetaright)
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 S-left] 'org-shiftmetaleft)
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 down] 'org-metadown)
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 up] 'org-metaup)
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 right] 'org-metaright)
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 left] 'org-metaleft)
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 return] 'org-meta-return)
        (define-key org-mode-map [27 S-return] 'org-insert-todo-heading)))
```

To find the bindings I needed to define, I got a listing of `org-mode-map` (with `C-h v`), and searched for `M-` to get all the bindings beginning with `M-`:

```
  (M-S-down . org-shiftmetadown)
  (M-S-up . org-shiftmetaup)
  (M-S-right . org-shiftmetaright)
  (M-S-left . org-shiftmetaleft)
  (M-down . org-metadown)
  (M-up . org-metaup)
  (M-right . org-metaright)
  (M-left . org-metaleft)
  (M-return . org-meta-return)
  (M-S-return . org-insert-todo-heading)
```

Each one of these lines is the basis for a corresponding `define-key` expression in the mode-hook shown above.  The transformation should be pretty obvious.  (The 27 in the `define-key` expressions is the code for <kbd>esc</kbd>.)

One would need to do this sort of thing for every single mode *X* that defines a key binding of the form `M-` followed by a non-character key sequence.  Specifically, for every such binding, one would have to include a `define-key` expression in a mode-hook for mode *X*.  Therefore, this approach is obviously a very laborious, fragile, and hard-to-maintain hack.  It does not do what the question requests, but instead painstakingly simulates it for certain special cases.  For this reason I did not post it as an answer, in the hopes that someone will post an actual answer to the original question.

Answer (score 6):

Emacs already has a key binding for “apply meta to the next key”, but it's awkward to type: [`C-x @ m`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html#Modifier-Keys) (alongside `C-x @ c` for “apply control to the next key”, etc.). It's implemented by a binding to `event-apply-meta-modifier` in [`function-key-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#index-local_002dfunction_002dkey_002dmap-1627).

Binding `escape` to `event-apply-meta-modifier` in `function-key-map` won't work because bindings there are shadowed by bindings in the global map or in minor mode maps, and these do have bindings for `escape`. (You could remove the global binding for `escape` but that would leave you at the mercy of minor modes.) Instead, you can bind `escape` in [`input-decode-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#index-input_002ddecode_002dmap-1626).

```
(define-key input-decode-map [escape] 'event-apply-meta-modifier)
(define-key global-map [?\M-\e M-escape] 'keyboard-escape-quit)
```

The second command binds `keyboard-escape-quit` to four presses of the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key; it's normally bound to three presses but that binding won't be accessible any longer.

In a terminal, this won't work, because the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key sends the `?\e` (ESC) character, not the `escape` key. Adding the same binding for `"\e"` would break all function keys that are encoded as escape sequences in a terminal.

If you want `M-key` bindings to take precedence over `ESC key` in a terminal, I can't think of a good way that doesn't require binding every key. You don't have to do it in every mode though: you can add a series of macros in the global map.

```
(require 'cl)
(dolist (key '(f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12
               left right up down prior next home end))
  (dolist ((chord `((,key)
                    (shift ,key)
                    (control ,key)
                    (control shift ,key))))
    (global-set-key (vector ?\e chord) (vector (cons 'meta chord)))))
```

On Linux, I do find that Org mode bindings work when I press <kbd>Escape</kbd> followed by <kbd>Left</kbd> etc., so you shouldn't need the terminal part, only the `input-decode-map` binding for `escape` for GUI-based Emacs.

Comment: Good post. I learned something.