# Map a key to act like a combination of modifiers

Tags: key-bindings, linux

I've got a keyboard, where pressing <kbd>M-C-S</kbd> is uncomfortable (Meta and control are under the thumbs and Shift is on the far end of the keyboard).  However, PageUp, PageDown, Home and End are in a very comfortable place.  I never use any of those keys though, so I was thinking, if it was possible to remap, say, Home to act like <kbd>M-C-S</kbd>, that would make my life a lot easier.  I would be even happier, if the solution wasn't Emacs-only, but on the system level (it is okay if it is Linux-only).

Comment: You want `Home` to be `Meta-Control-Shift-`?

Comment: @abo-abo Either that, or Control-Shift, it's right under Meta, so it would be ok to press them both at once.

Comment: @Malabarba, it's not a duplicate. The question is quite interesting and apparently can't be solved with `xmodmap`.

Comment: @abo-abo the answer to the other question was "it can't be done with emacs". I don't think the additional complexity of this question will lead to a different answer. Still, I'll err on the side of niceness right now, and leave it open. The community can still vote to close if they agree with me.

Comment: @Malabarba, but OP isn't asking for specifically an "in-emacs" answer. A system-specific setting would be acceptable.

Comment: This is the closes to the answer I found so far: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/mapping-key-combination-with-xmodmap but I hoped there could be an alternative.

Comment: Unlike the situation in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/mapping-key-combination-with-xmodmap this one can be solved at the system level with XKB (but not with xmodmap, which is simpler but less powerful). I'm not an XKB expert but someone on [unix.se] surely knows how to do it. Alternatively, you can solve this in a not very nice way with xmodmap and Emacs, by making e.g. the `End` key the `super` modifier and translating each super-key key combination to C-M-S-key.

Comment: [This Unix & Linux question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157834/how-to-bind-altgr-to-ctrl-alt) asks how to do this with XKB. On second thoughts it doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 5):

A pure Emacs solution that doesn't do exactly what you're asking, but close, would be to make e.g. <kbd>Home</kbd> be a key that adds the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifiers to the next key that you press. That is, rather than press <kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>*key*</kbd>, you would press <kbd>Home</kbd>then <kbd>*key*</kbd>.

Emacs has a built-in feature to add a modifier to the next key, [bound to the unwieldy `C-x @ letter`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html#Modifier-Keys) by default, e.g. if you type `C-x @ m a` it's interpreted as `M-a`. This is implemented via [`function-key-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#index-local_002dfunction_002dkey_002dmap-1627). Bindings in `function-key-map` are overridden by key bindings in most maps, including the global keymap; if you want your binding to take precedence, define it in [`input-decode-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html#index-input_002ddecode_002dmap-1802) instead. I've written a bit about it [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3992/how-to-extend-the-esc-m-translation-to-non-character-keys/3993#3993).

You can adapt this mechanism to bind `home` to `event-apply-control-meta-shift-modifiers`.

```
(defun event-symbol-add-modifiers (symbol prefixes)
  (let* ((name (symbol-name symbol))
         (parts (split-string name "-"))
         (old-modifiers nil))
    (while parts
      (if (= (length (car parts)) 1)
          (setq old-modifiers (cons (aref (car parts) 0) old-modifiers)))
      (setq parts (cdr parts)))
    (while prefixes
      (if (not (memq (car prefixes) old-modifiers))
          (setq name (concat (list (car prefixes) ?-) name)))
        (setq prefixes (cdr prefixes)))
    (intern name)))
(defun event-apply-modifiers (event mask prefixes)
  (cond
   ((numberp event)
    (logior mask event))
   ((symbolp event)
    (event-symbol-add-modifiers event prefixes))
   ((consp event)
    (cons (event-symbol-add-modifiers (car event) prefixes) (cdr event)))
   (t event)))
(defun event-apply-control-meta-shift-modifiers (ignore-prompt)
  "\\<function-key-map>Add the Ctrl, Meta and Shift modifier to the following event.
For example, type \\[event-apply-control-meta-shift-modifiers] & to enter Ctrl-Meta-Shift-&."
  (vector (event-apply-modifiers (read-event) #xe000000 '(?C ?M ?S))))
(define-key input-decode-map [home] 'event-apply-control-meta-shift-modifiers)
```

(`event-apply-modifiers` is a highly simplified version of Emacs's `event-apply-modifier` and may be inferior in some circumstances. Minimally tested.)

Comment: hi, this doesn't work with shift modifiers. Do you have any idea how to improve this?   (defun event-apply-control-shift-modifier (_ignore-prompt)
    (vector (event-apply-modifiers (read-event) #x6000000 '(?C ?S))))  it doesn't trigger my C-S-s key binding

Comment: @Amos I forgot to mention that if you're using a key that already has a global binding and you want to bypass that binding, you need to use `input-decode-map` instead of `function-key-map`.

Comment: well it still doesn't work. here is my config file https://la.wentropy.com/LbMM
  and i use urxvt to send \030@aS

Comment: @Amos Ah. If you're in a terminal, the terminal sends an escape sequence which is translated to `home`. The result of the translation doesn't undergo translation again. You need to bind the escape sequence to `event-apply-…` directly, something like `(define-key input-decode-map "\eOH" 'event-apply-…)`. Check what escape sequence the `home` key sends by pressing `C-q home` in the `*scratch*` buffer. The first `^[` is an escape character, written `\e` in a string literal.

Comment: hmm, but i don't use `home` key. I'm trying to bind `C-S-s`

Comment: @Amos In your question, you asked how to “remap, say, Home to act like M-C-S”. What are you trying to do exactly? If you're now trying to do something different, you should ask a new question.

Comment: well, `the terminal sends an escape sequence which is translated to home`. i have no idea i did that. i just need terminal emacs to accept `Ctrl-Shift-s` hotkey

Comment: @Amos What do you mean by “accept Ctrl-Shift-s hotkey”? Do you want to type `Ctrl+Shift+s` or `Home` then `s`?

Comment: I mean typing `Ctrl+Shift+s` and make terminal emacs react on that. I have never use `Home` ...

Comment: @Amos Well that's a completely different question! Which has been answered before for xterm: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal/13957#13957 In urxvt, you need to manually configure different escape sequences for modifier combinations such as Ctrl+Shfit with the `URxvt.keysym.` resources.