# How to revert evil insert state binding of the escape key?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I have remapped the `evil-normal-state` command bound to `ESC` in Evil Insert mode to `C-o` since the escape key is more difficult to reach on my keyboard than typing `C-o`. Now I want to use the original meaning of the `ESC` key as a prefix key instead.

I tried:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "ESC") 'ESC-prefix)
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Seems to work if I use `"<escape>"` instead of `"ESC"`. But it would be interesting to get an explanation for this

Comment: Also found some other answers that could help to clarify the difference: See: [What is the difference between TAB and <tab>?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9631/260) and [How to extend the ESC -> M- translation to non-character keys?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3993/260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ESC` is the escape character, `<escape>` is the symbol generated by pressing the ESC key **in X**. The escape character is generated when pressing something key together with the meta-key like `M-x`, that actually generates two key events, first the ESC event, second the `x`. (actually, that's only true in terminal mode since in X `M-x` generates a special event, but this event is mapped to `ESC x`). The problem is that in terminal mode the escape key does not generate `<escape>` but also `ESC`.

That said, in order to have the escape key working correctly in terminal, Evil has to catch the ESC event and possibly translate it to `<escape>` after some timeout (otherwise either bindings like `M-x` or leaving insert state with `ESC` would not work). In other words, the event `ESC` typically never reaches those keymaps because it is translated to `<escape>` before. The variable `evil-intercept-esc` can be used to customize this behavior (but only in newly created frames).