# org-mode sans arrow keys

Tags: org-mode, keymap

Org-mode keymapping defaults to using the arrow keys for commons functions.  Has anyone sanely remapped their org-mode settings to entirely avoid arrow keys?

Please share.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without remapping, you can already get by pretty well without arrow keys.

`C-c C-x C-h` in an Org buffer:

```
C-c C-x D       org-shiftmetadown
C-c C-x L       org-shiftmetaleft
C-c C-x R       org-shiftmetaright
C-c C-x U       org-shiftmetaup
C-c C-x d       org-metadown
C-c C-x l       org-metaleft
C-c C-x m       org-meta-return
C-c C-x r       org-metaright
C-c C-x u       org-metaup
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, whether or not these keys are set depends on your environment  (for example, if you are using Emacs in the terminal or as a daemon). To make sure these always show up, you can enable `org-use-extra-keys`. (This needs to be done before Org is loaded.)

Comment: Those bindings don't appear in my org buffer.  When I describe-mode, I see:

<M-S-down>      org-shiftmetadown
<M-S-left>      org-shiftmetaleft
  ...

Comment: These are defined by `org-use-extra-keys` which is on be default for example in a terminal.  Customize that option to get this also in a windowed emacs.  Cf. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3991/2710

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Yay, finally a moment to shamelessly advertise http://abo-abo.github.io/worf/README.html.

<kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> are arrows.

<kbd>c</kbd> toggles change mode:

```
(worf-defverb
 "change"
 '(("j" org-metadown)
   ("k" org-metaup)
   ("h" org-metaleft)
   ("l" org-metaright)
   ("t" org-set-tags :disable)
   ("n" worf-change-name :disable :break)
   ("a" org-meta-return :disable :break)))
```

<kbd>cf</kbd> enters change tree mode:

```
(worf-defverb
 "change-tree"
 '(("j" org-shiftmetadown)
   ("k" org-shiftmetaup)
   ("h" org-shiftmetaleft)
   ("l" org-shiftmetaright)))
```

<kbd>cs</kbd> enters change shift mode:

```
(worf-defverb
 "change-shift"
 '(("j" org-shiftdown)
   ("k" org-shiftup)
   ("h" org-shiftleft)
   ("l" org-shiftright)))
```

<kbd>cr</kbd> enters change shift-control mode:

```
(worf-defverb
 "change-shiftcontrol"
 '(("j" org-shiftcontroldown)
   ("k" org-shiftcontrolup)
   ("h" org-shiftcontrolleft)
   ("l" org-shiftcontrolright)))
```

<kbd>q</kbd> will quit any mode and make <kbd>hjkl</kbd> arrows again.

I'm still experimenting with the package, so these bindings might
change in the future. If you want to try it, it's in MELPA.  And as
long as you're trying, check out <kbd>g</kbd> - it's the best feature
of the package.